# Hot to Add Cookies to the httpcontextbase from unit test and accessing from controller

Tags: c#, testing, cookies

I am trying to unit test one of my controller action method but having issue with HttpContext.

Below is the Action method code which reads the id from the cookie.

```
 public decimal GetId()
    {
        string result = "0"; 
        try
        {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Id"];
     //Getting error in above line of code saying the Httpcontext is null
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
              result = ticket.UserData.Substring(0, ticket.UserData.IndexOf("|"));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerHelper.LogError("GetID", ex.ToString());
        }

        return Convert.ToDecimal(result);
    }
```

And when I try to unit test the controller Action method getting error in below line of code

```
   HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Id"];
```

HttpContext becoming null even though I fake the httpcontextbase and added cookie to it in my Unit test code.

Please help. I spent whole day but still unable to figure it out why HttpContext becoming null.

Thanks in advance,
VJ

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private static IRequestCookieCollection MockRequestCookieCollection(string key, string value)
    {
        var requestFeature = new HttpRequestFeature();
        var featureCollection = new FeatureCollection();

        requestFeature.Headers = new HeaderDictionary();
        requestFeature.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, new StringValues(key + "=" + value));

        featureCollection.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(requestFeature);

        var cookiesFeature = new RequestCookiesFeature(featureCollection);

        return cookiesFeature.Cookies;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Id"];
```

instead of using

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Id"];
```

in controller, since I am creating the `System.Web.Httpcontext` in my unit test case.